# What's the effect of fillMode being kCAFillModeBackwards?

Tags: ios, core-animation

> kCAFillModeBackwards
>   The receiver clamps values before zero to zero when the animation is completed.

What does the meaning of "clamping values before zero to zero"? A simple example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since no one gave me an answer and the documentation of *fillMode* is really bad, I did a research and re-document it [here](http://wangling.me/2011/06/time-warp-in-animation.html).

> **kCAFillModeRemoved**
>
> The receiver does not appear until it begins and is removed from the presentation when it is completed.
>
> **kCAFillModeForwards**
>
> The receiver does not appear until it begins but remains visible in its final state when it is completed.
>
> **kCAFillModeBackwards**
>
> The receiver appears in its initial state before it begins but is removed from the presentation when it is completed.
>
> **kCAFillModeBoth**
>
> The receiver appears in its initial state before it begins and remains visible in its final state when it is completed.

Comment: Finally someone explains fillMode in a way I can understand. It would be wonderful if the answer could also be here on stack overflow. Hint, hint...

Comment: who is the receiver and who is "it" ?

Comment: To see the effect of the various settings, don't forget to set the removedOnCompletion property to NO (by default it is YES).

Comment: Which one is the default?

Comment: @BenLu kCAFillModeRemoved is the default

Comment: @eddardstark The 'receiver' is the CALayer to which you apply the animation. 'It' is the CAAnimation.

Comment: It's worth reading author's blog post: https://wangling.me/2011/06/time-warp-in-animation.html You will feel much more clear on the fill mode.

Answer (score 0):

Default : kCAFillModeRemoved - plays the animation at begin time and simply removes animation from view layer.

kCAFillModeBackwards - loads the animation first frame until animation begins and then removes animation completely from view layer after completion.

kCAFillModeForwards - opposite of above. Keep last frame of animation, unless explicitly removed, even after animation completes.

kCAFillModeBoth - kCAFillModeForwards + kCAFillModeBackwards